# Swift UITapGestureRecognizer Slow

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, uitapgesturerecognizer, gestures

I am having delays with using the UITapGestureRecognizer, I know this will be due to:-

```
singleTap.requireGestureRecognizerToFail(doubleTap)
```

but this is required due to single tap being called at the same time as a double tap. Is there another way around this issue?

```
let singleTap:UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("singleTap:"))
singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
singleTap.requireGestureRecognizerToFail(doubleTap)
view.addGestureRecognizer(singleTap)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you require that the double tap fails before the single tap can be detected then there is absolutely no way that you can get around this.

Could you get around this by requiring that your single taps fails before your double tap recognises?

```
doubleTap.requireGestureRecognizerToFail(singleTap)
```

That should mean that the double tap would only fire if the single tap wasn't detected, essentially prioritising the single tap

Comment: Yeah its supper annoying as i require single tap for a walk to location, and a double tap to run to the location. i have tried removing the fail and it just makes my character glitch out.

Adding the fail to doubleTap prevents me using the doubleTap sadly :(

I do appreciate your help Liam, Thank You!

Comment: Ahh yeah sorry, that makes sense! Unfortunately its the design of the gesture recognition system so there isn't much that can be done here, other than using gestures in a different way to achieve what you want? Maybe play around with using different types of gestures or maybe a flick/swipe to run instead? Good Luck!

Comment: Also, from apples documentation: "If you want these two actions to be mutually exclusive, your single tap recognizer must require the double tap recognizer to fail. However, your single tap actions will lag a little behind the user’s input because the single tap recognizer is delayed until the double tap recognizer fails." (via, https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizer_basics/GestureRecognizer_basics.html). It kind of explains your scenario and why it happens :)